# How to update Oracle table by getting table name and column names from database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I want to make a form which updates some data in multi tables in my oracle database, and I have to use this form in different organizations.

Tables what I want to update I'll get from table dba_tab_columns by using this script

```
SELECT table_name, column_name
  FROM dba_tab_columns
 WHERE upper(column_name) LIKE 'PATIENT%'
```

My problem is if I run the above script I'll get unpredictable set of data, I mean some organization they have tables more than other, and some they have a similar table with different name. So I want from my form first to read all table name and column names with the above script and then update that table with something like the following script.

```
UPDATE <target_table_name>
   SET <target_column_name> = :BLK_TOOLS.PATIENT_ID1
 WHERE <target_column_name> = :BLK_TOOLS.PATIENT_ID2;
```

How to do it?

i try to do database procedure as following but it's not working.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE HIMS.merge9898
  (PID1 NUMBER, PID2 VARCHAR2) IS
 TYPE tab_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(40)
    INDEX BY binary_integer;
 TYPE col_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(40)
    INDEX BY binary_integer;
  v_dml_str VARCHAR2            (200);
  v_tab_array    tab_array;
  v_col_array    col_array;
BEGIN

  SELECT table_name,column_name BULK COLLECT
    INTO v_tab_array,v_col_array
  FROM sys.dba_tab_columns
  where upper(column_name) like'PATIENT%' and global_stats='YES';

  FOR i IN v_tab_array.first..v_tab_array.last LOOP
    v_dml_str := 'UPDATE '
                 || v_tab_array(i)
                 || ' SET '||v_col_array(i)||' = :PID1'
                 || ' WHERE '||v_col_array(i)||' = :PID2';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_dml_str USING PID1, PID2;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

and display this error

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
12/3     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
14/12    PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Comment: you need dynamic sql - `execute immediate`

Comment: what is `emp_rec.column_name` in your example?

Comment: sry by mistake there are no emp_rec

Comment: @Tatiana I try to do "database procedure"  so i ll call it from form, but still not working. Any Idea ?

Comment: you make your update according to `dba_tab_columns` information. But you may have no rights to update some tables from that list. If you don't have right to do it - you will get error - `table or view does not exist`. Use `all_tab_columns` table. Here store all objects on which you have rights

Comment: @Tatiana I changed sys.dba_tab_columns to SYS.all_tab_columns. now this error came when i execute *
`ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "HIMS.MERGE9898", line 24
ORA-06512: at line 1`

Comment: You have no rights to update some of that tables. If you change it to user)tab_columns it will work 100% because it will be only yours tables. But it depends on your requirements if you need not only yours tables

Comment: @Tatiana I have several tables in several schema, if i update manual it will update, so i have rights to update

Comment: try this one - add in your select column `OWNER` and  when updating - `'UPDATE '  || v_owner_array(i) ||'.'||v_tab_array(i) .....`

Comment: @Tatiana I add it but it give same error

Comment: @Tatiana i Add update any table (system privilege) to my user and now it's working, thanks for every thing

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.

```
BEGIN
FOR tab IN (select table_name,column_name from dba_tab_columns where upper(column_name) like'PATIENT%') LOOP
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE '||tab.table_name||
' SET '|| tab.column_name ||' = '|| :BLK_TOOLS.PATIENT_ID1 || 
' WHERE '||tab.column_name ||' = '|| :BLK_TOOLS.PATIENT_ID2;
END LOOP;
END;
```

OR

```
BEGIN
FOR tab IN (select table_name,column_name from dba_tab_columns where upper(column_name) like'PATIENT%') LOOP
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE '||tab.table_name||
' SET '|| tab.column_name ||' = :1
 WHERE '||tab.column_name ||' = :2'
USING :BLK_TOOLS.PATIENT_ID1 ,:BLK_TOOLS.PATIENT_ID2 ;
END LOOP;
END;
```

not sure about using bind variables in dynamic sql

Comment: Error 103 at line 8, column 9
Encountered the symbol "IMMEDIATE" when expecting one of the following:

:=.(@%;
The symbol ".=was inserted before "IMMEDIATE" to countine.

Comment: I am  not sure in using bind variables with execute immediate. But try updated answer. And it is better to post error number, not just descreption

Comment: Must be like this: `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE '||tab.table_name||
' SET '|| tab.column_name ||' = :p1 WHERE '||tab.column_name ||' = :p2' USING BLK_TOOLS.PATIENT_ID1, BLK_TOOLS.PATIENT_ID2;`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit as I understand BLK_TOOLS.PATIENT_ID1 is a bind variable which is used with `:` mark. so not sure if it will works like this

Comment: @Tatiana no it is not (at least for Oracle). Syntax must be as given in my comment.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit it give same error , not working

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/literals-substitution-variables-and-bind-variables#bind_variables `--Bind variables can be declared in your SQL*Plus script.
VARIABLE  s_table_name  varchar2(30)
     
--Preface a bind variable with a colon to reference it
--in a PL/SQL block.
BEGIN
  :s_table_name := 'EMPLOYEE';
END;`

Comment: @Tatiana I tested in oacle form and it mot showing Error 103

Comment: @Al-Hanashi so :BLK_TOOLS.PATIENT_ID2 is item on form?

Comment: @Al-Hanashi Add exception block and show error, e.g. `message(SQLCODE ||'   '||SQLERRM)`

Comment: @Tatiana ya  :BLK_TOOLS.PATIENT_ID1 and  :BLK_TOOLS.PATIENT_ID2 item on form